# Argentinian Exit node not working on Tor

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

Windows 10 with
Tor browser 6.5.2 (based on Mozilla Firefox 45.9.0)

My problem is that I was using  exit node from Argentina (`AR`) in my `torrc` file without problem till now. 
From today with AR exit node - I can not connect to any websites. As soon as I remove the AR exit node - Tor makes a random circuit and everything is working. Also as a test if I put GB as exit node - that is also working.

So what is wrong with AR exit node?

This is the only change I have made in torrc file. And I even reinstalled TOR and tried it again - still not working.

```
StrictNodes 1
ExitNodes {AR}
```

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome. Also I am new here - let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) has information about relays in the Tor network. When you search for [`country:ar`](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/country:ar) Atlas outputs:

> No Results found!
>   No Tor relays matched your query :(

This means that currently there are no active Tor relays in Argentina. If you know relay operators in Argentina you can encourage them to run their relays again or ask other people to start running relays there.